# Transferring from DropBox to different cloud provider, preserving history

Tags: dropbox, onedrive, google-drive

Is there a good way to transfer files and their history into another provider or to a source code repo?

When you move from DropBox to another provider, like Google Drive or Microsoft's Onedrive... is it possible to preserve the historical versions of those files, or do you forfeit when moving?

Comment: The other two providers you list don't have file history.  What you want does not exist, and even if it did exist, we could not recomend the service.